# Cube action to show product page in website

Tags: ssas

I created a cube action to open google maps for dimention location (classic book example) and now I'm trying to build a cube action to open webpage for the dimension product.

Here is what I have so far:

Target Object: `DimProduct.[Product Description]`

Action expression: `"http://www..../"+DimProduct.[Product ID].CurrentMember.Member_Caption`

As you can see, user browses the dimention by product description, but website takes product ID.

Under this action, `DimProduct.[Product ID].CurrentMember.Member_Caption` is translated as "all", so, the final expression becomes `"http://www..../all"`, rather than `"http://www..../134"` (134 in an example of product ID).

How can I grab the product ID in a case like this?
Any help appreciated.

Lab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part problem is the "potential" differences in granularity between [Dim Product].[Product Description] and [Dim Product].[Product].  In the AdventureWorks data model, there is a 1-many relationship between these two...

[image]

So in my screenshot above, if the user right-clicks cell A10, which product ID do you want to use?  You code...

```
[Dim Product].[Product ID].CurrentMember.Member_Caption
```

...is just saying, "use the current one".  So instead, you would want to try something like...

```
[Dim Product].[Product ID].FirstChild.Member_Caption
```

Using FirstChild says, "just take the first one in the list and use that".

Another issue is that you may need to use the "Member_Key" property instead of "Member_Caption"...but this depends on how your product dimension is setup.  [Here's some info on the different member properties.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145528.aspx)